# bootstrap: align elements of list in dropdown button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There is a group of buttons with drop-down list:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">
        Some text
    </button>

    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href='#'>Item1  Value1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Another_Item Value1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to make Item is left-aligned, and Value - on the right? (Using Twitter Bootstrap classes)

Answer (score 0):

There is no class in the Bootstrap for this, but you can add styles for this purpose

```
<button class="btn btn-width-text">
    Some text
</button>

<button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-with-caret" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

.btn-width-text{
  float: right;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.btn-with-caret{
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```